# Function for adding a shortcode to product template not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So I need to add a shortcode `[stag_sidebar id='product']` to each single product page in Woocommerce. Specifically in short description. Here's what I tried but this isn't working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'custom_woocommerce_short_description' );

function custom_woocommerce_short_description( $description ) {
global $post;

$description = $description . do_shortcode('[stag_sidebar id='product']') ;

return $description;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't working? What is the issue? What happens?

Comment: Page just gets frozen. White screen. I noticed when I put a shortcode like this: [testshortcode] into function then the page is loading normally.

Comment: You get a white screen because you have a php error, I answered below. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error on your do_shortcode function, you are using single quotes twice. You should escape them, or alternate single and double quotes, like this:

```
$description = $description . do_shortcode("[stag_sidebar id='product']") ;
```

Comment: Thanks, now the page goes through but seems like the shortcode's value isn't displaying on single product page..

Comment: If you add the shortcode in the content on the product's single page it works? Maybe the shortcode is not defined corectly.

Comment: What would be the way to define it?

Comment: It should be defined with the add_shortcode function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode. If it works in the content I really can't tell what is the problem, your code seems fine.